# Can you list only the questions in tag search in the iOS app?

Tags: support, search, ios-app, mobile-web, tag-search

Using the Stack Exchange iOS app 1.6.6.2 05/26/2017. I want to list only the questions (no answers) as the result of a tag search.

By default both questions (Q:) and answers (A:) are returned. For example:

[image]

As far as I can tell, the desktop site provides only the questions. I am looking for achieving the same thing on mobile.

[image]

Comment: does the `is:q` search parameter work on mobile?

Comment: @rene `[awk] is:question`  does not return any result in the mobile app for me

Comment: Hmm, OK. too bad. I'm afraid that isn't possible then :(

Comment: @rene the site for my search query with `is:q` was wrong. Thanks for your suggestion. It works now.

Comment: Ha! Great! A happy customer! Thanks for flying with us, enjoy your stay...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`is:q` as [rene mentions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299657/can-you-list-only-the-questions-in-tag-search-in-the-ios-app/299658#comment973891_299657) *does* work. Your problem was that you were using the wrong site to search; there are no [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) questions on Meta Stack Exchange.

[image]
[image]

<sub>(click to enlarge)</sub>

Comment: Ohh my bad. Let me re-edit my question.

Comment: After I have removed the snapshot with the wrong MetaSE site, your answer's `no awk questions on Meta Stack Exchange.` section may be confusing to future readers. You may consider to rephrase that.

Comment: It's already in the past tense (it used to be in the present).